# An error has occured while executing Python code while doing home range analysis (Qgis 1.8.0)

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

It keeps appearing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Worten/.qgis//python/plugins\HomeRange_plugin\HRplugin_dialog.py", line 80, in 
    QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, SIGNAL("accepted()"), lambda mth=mth: self.run(mth))
  File "C:/Users/Worten/.qgis//python/plugins\HomeRange_plugin\HRplugin_dialog.py", line 186, in run
    if not robjects.r.require(i)[0]:
NameError: global name 'robjects' is not defined

Python version:
2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Python path: ['C:\\Users\\Worten\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 
'C:\\Users\\Worten\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 
'C:\\Users\\Worten\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\elevation', 
'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python', 
'C:/Users/Worten/.qgis//python', 
'C:/Users/Worten/.qgis//python/plugins', 
'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 
'.', 
'C:\\Users\\Worten\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\ziplayers\\logic', 
'C:\\Users\\Worten\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\ziplayers\\gui', 
'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 
'C:/Users/Worten/Desktop/Relatorio Anual 2012 - 2 de Mar\xc3\xa7o - 30 de Julho']
```

Answer (score 2):

The home range plugin has been replaced by the Animove plugin for Sextante. This plugin should be running with QGIS 1.8.0.

You have to enable experimental plugins in the Installers Options tab to see it in the Official QGIS repository.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have all the dependencies installed:

- R
- rpy2 (the only one [included in OSGeo4W](http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/versions.html))
- adehabitat
- rgdal

If that's already the case, it looks like a bug in the plugin, so contact the author.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Home Range plugin you **must** use QGIS 1.7.3

The reason is that the developer of the RPY2 package stopped (for lack of support from the users) to support Windows builds for pyhton > 2.5 and from the release 1.7.4 QGIS uses python 2.7.

I already explained in mailing lists and also privately this issue to many researchers and the bottom line is that who uses this extension should make an effort (put together some $) to allow the developer (Anne Ghisla) to rewrite the tool in a way that RPY2 is no more necessary and add it to the new SEXTANTE toolbox.

Adding the HR tool to SEXTANTE would greatly improve the possibilities as it would be possible to integrate the Home Ranges computations in large/complex models with parts done with GRASS, R, SAGA, etc.